# Is it normal to change targetNamespace for the same WebService depends on host where this WS was deployed?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I have access to some WebService that was deployed on several hosts (dev environment and test environment). For **dev** environment in its wsdl I see `targetNamespace="http://somews.somecompany.com/DEV/PI_WEB_ORDER"` for **test** environment - `targetNamespace="http://somews.somecompany.com/TEST/PI_WEB_ORDER"`. Target namespaces are different, the rest of wsdl content is the same. I am confused because the classes are generated with WSDL from **dev** don't work properly with **test** host.

In my opinion targetNamespace mustn't be changed depends on host or environment. Is it correct?